# My script for Sprinting and Crouching doesn't work;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am actually trying to make the player Sprint by pressing the <kbd>LeftShift</kbd> key and Crouch by pressing the <kbd>LeftControl</kbd> Key.

I attached the C# Code at the bottom.
So here, the Shift key works, because I tested by using Debug.Log("Sprint Triggered") when the key is pressed, and the Crouch key works too in the same way.

But, when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, the speed of the player doesn't change at all. And also, when I press crouch, the player just gives a really really quick jump up.

I have set all the variables correctly, I double checked them. But I don't know why there is no change in the motion of the body.

Let me know if you need any more details

```cs
public class SprintingCrouching : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerMovement playerMovement;
    public float sprintSpeed = 10f;
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float crouchSpeed = 2f;
    private Transform look_rot;
    private float standHeight = 1.6f;
    private float crouchHeight = 1f;
    private bool isCrouching = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        playerMovement = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        look_rot = transform.GetChild(0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        SprintPlayer();
        Crouch();
        Debug.Log(playerMovement.speed);
    }
    void SprintPlayer()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            Debug.Log("Sprint Triggered");
            playerMovement.speed = sprintSpeed;
        }
    }
    void Crouch()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl))
        {
            Debug.Log("Crouch Triggered");
            look_rot.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, standHeight, 0f);
            playerMovement.speed = moveSpeed;
            isCrouching = false;
        }
        else
        {
            look_rot.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, crouchHeight, 0f);
            playerMovement.speed = moveSpeed;
            isCrouching = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you hold only Shift you will always end up in the `else` block of `Crouch` - effectively making the `SprintPlayer` method useless

Comment: What do you think  I should change ?

Comment: You need to have some kind of state handling. So you need to keep track of what states are active (sprint and/or crouch) then adjust the speed accordingly. Right now you are only checking inputs, which is not enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body is changing, just that its only in the moment you press down the key and then it returns to its normal state. You can make a function that checks for holding/releasing certain keys and modifies a bool variable that your sprint/crouch function will read, like this:

```
public class SprintingCrouching : MonoBehaviour
{
private PlayerMovement playerMovement;
public float sprintSpeed = 10f;
public float moveSpeed = 5f;
public float crouchSpeed = 2f;
private Transform look_rot;
private float standHeight = 1.6f;
private float crouchHeight = 1f;
private bool isCrouching = false, isSprinting = false;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake()
{
    playerMovement = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
    look_rot = transform.GetChild(0);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    GetInput();
    SprintPlayer();
    Crouch();
    Debug.Log(playerMovement.speed);
}


void GetInput()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) isSprinting = true;
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift)) isSprinting = false;
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftControl)) isCrouching = true;
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftControl)) isCrouching = false;

    //GetKeyUp detects when a key is released.
}

void SprintPlayer()
{
    if(isSprinting)
    {
        Debug.Log("Sprint Triggered");
        playerMovement.speed = sprintSpeed;
    }
    else
    {
        playerMovement.speed = moveSpeed;
    }
}
void Crouch()
{
    if(isCrouching)
    {
        Debug.Log("Crouch Triggered");
        look_rot.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, standHeight, 0f);//Maybe this is supposed to be crouchHeight instead?(because you are enabling crouch)
        playerMovement.speed = moveSpeed; //Maybe you tried to use crouchSpeed here instead?
    }
    else
    {
        look_rot.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, crouchHeight, 0f); //Maybe this is supposed to be standHeight(because it's disabling crouch)
        playerMovement.speed = moveSpeed;
    }
}

}
```

Also a note to make your code cleaner you can declare similar variables using a , like so:

```
int var1 = 3, var2 = 7;
```

Comment: This isn't going to fix the problem at all, because `Update()` calls `SprintPlayer()` and then `Crouch()`. It doesn't matter what `SprintPlayer()` is doing with `playerMovement.speed` because `Crouch()` only has two options, `isCrouching` and `else`, and both of those cases set `playerMovement.speed = moveSpeed`.

Comment: Use `Input.GetKey` instead of keeping track of it yourself `https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html`

Answer (score 0):

Hey ill help as i have made a few, movement systems with unity and c#

```
public Transform Body;

class Movement
{

public Transform Body;
crouchScale = new Vector3(0f, standHeight/2, 0f);

if(Input.getButtonDown(0)
{
 Body.localPostion = new Vector3(0f, crouchScale, 0f);
}
else
 {
 return;
 }
```